# Why is a UNION on two numbers more efficient than their sum?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance

We want to ensure that there are no more than maxCount palettes at a location (with a certain type of inventory).
In order to ensure that, we sum up locations with palettes on them or locations to which palettes will be located. Both statements work fine. However, my initial draft was not very performant. My advisor came up with a different draft which is much faster, but he could not explain why.

Slow statement:

```
 AND maxCount > ( 
    SELECT 
        trptoloc+atloc
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(DISTINCT loc2.locnam) AS atloc
            FROM
                loc_t loc2,
                pal_t pal,
                inv_t inv,
                art_t art
            WHERE
                loc.group = loc2.group
                AND   pal.locnam = loc2.locnam
                AND   inv.palnam = pal.palnam
                AND   inv.artid = art.artid
                AND   AND   art.feature = value
        ),
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(DISTINCT loc2.locnam) AS trptoloc
            FROM
                trp_t trp,
                loc_t loc2,
                inv_t inv,
                art_t art
            WHERE
                trp.locnamezl = loc2.locnam
                AND   trp.palnam = inv.palnam
                AND   loc.group = loc2.group
                AND   inv.artid = art.artid
                AND   art.feature = value;
        )
)
```

Faster statement:

```
AND maxCount > (
 SELECT
 SUM(invpal)
 FROM
 (SELECT
    COUNT(distinct inv.palnam) AS invpal
    FROM
        inv_t inv,
        art_t art,
        pal_t pal,
        loc_T loc2
    WHERE
        inv.artid = art.artid
        AND   loc.group = loc2.group
        AND   pal.locnam = loc2.locnam
        AND   inv.palnam = pal.palnam
        AND   art.feature = value;
  UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(distinct inv.palnam) AS invpal
    FROM
        inv_t inv,
        art_t art,
        trp_t trp,
        loc_T loc2
    WHERE
        trp.locnamezl = loc2.locnam
        AND   trp.palnam = inv.palnam
        AND   loc.group = loc2.group
        AND   inv.artid = art.artid
        AND   art.feature = value;
)
)
```

Any hint or link that will help me understand the performance difference is appreciated!

Comment: Your adviser should learn how to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  You should too.

Comment: You should check the execution plans of both queries.

Comment: Maybe (some of) the five tables inside the query are actually (multi-table) views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example is **joining two inline views**. That's not necessarily bad, but if you look at the explain plan, Oracle is probably doing nested loops over the two views, meaning that it loads them both separately into memory and then joins them together (on nothing - it's a cross/cartesian join).

In the UNION ALL example, the optimizer doesn't have to do anything complicated - it just runs the first half, then runs the second half, then sums the two rows. It doesn't try to keep both queries in memory at the same time so that it can compare them to each other.

As a side note, [there are often ways to rewrite inline views to perform better](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_tuning_in_line_views.htm), although it can make your code harder to understand. You haven't given us many details about your table structure or data, but I think you can probably rewrite this query so it only reads each table once instead of twice, e.g.

```
AND maxCount > (
  select count(distinct inv.palnam)
  from inv_t inv
  join art_t art 
        on inv.artid = art.artid and art.feature = value
  join loc_T loc2 
        on loc.group = loc2.group
  left join pal_t pal 
        on pal.locnam = loc2.locnam
        and pal.palnam = inv.palnam 
  left join trp_t trp 
        on trp.palnam = inv.palnam
        and trp.locnamezl = loc2.locnam
  where pal.palnam is not null or trp.palnam is not null
)
```

I also rewrote it to use explicit ANSI joins, like Gordon was suggesting.

Comment: Thank you! I'm pretty new to oracle sql, seems like I have to do a lot more reading. I'll try to get used to explicit joins in the future, that seems like a better way to keep track of what will be happening internally.

Comment: @MelanieB. The industry as a whole is shifting towards ANSI joins, but a lot of legacy code is written in Oracle syntax, so it helps to understand both.

Comment: @kfinity - actually the implicit join comma isn't "oracle syntax". It is **ANSI 89** standard syntax. It's just that Oracle is one of the oldest and most successful RDBMS products of all time, so there's probably a lot more legacy Oracle SQL than any other database.